# Python Threading.timer()

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I'm trying to perform a function after a time interval.
The time interval is controlled from Ftp server Notepad file.
The user updates notepad file which updates the time interval after some time.
But it is not working it reads the data from the notepad file on startup and the threading.timer use old time it doesn't update Code even the data in notepad file is changed by us

```
def Dataflow():        
    try:
        ftp = FTP('Domain')
        ftp.login('username', 'password')
        ftp.cwd('/directory where notepad file is saved')

        server_file='control.txt' #The Text file that will control the data flow

        local_file=r'C:\Users\Public\flow.txt' #The Local location of file which will catch data
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + server_file , open(local_file, 'wb').write)  # To download the Dataflow rate from the notepad in ftp server
        local_file = open(r'C:\Users\Public\flow.txt','r')
        temp_store = int(local_file.read(20)) #storing the data of notepad file in variable
        local_file.close(); ftp.close()
        return temp_store
    except:
        pass

def function():
           do something 

time = threading.timer(Dataflow(), function)
time.start()
```

Comment: You are not showing the code to read the file.

Comment: @StephenRauch Now check the code

Comment: I see nothing here that reads a file and sets a timeout.

Comment: the time is enter in notepad file by user manually something like user opens the control.txt file and write 60 in it and saves it . then the Dataflow() functions downloads that file and stores locally in flow.txt file then reads the data from flow.txt files and stores in a variable and return s it where the function is called and it is called in this line
time = threading.timer(Dataflow(), function)
time.start()

Comment: That is WONDERFUL!  But that is not shown here, so how do you expect us to help you with that?

Comment: I have posted the code.

Comment: consider I have entered 60 in the control.txt file   then dry run the code You will know whats happening